# auto-generated current date in a column using materialtable in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-table

when i want to add a new row in the materialtable i need that the field date must be auto-generated and taks the value of current date and this date can't be editable in update or in insert
[image]

this my solution but its not working

```
      columns: [
              {
...,
                    title: 'date',
                    field: 'fieldDate',
                    type: 'date',
                    default: new Date()
                },
...]
```

Comment: Could you provide an online demo? Which may help others to catch up with the problem you are facing quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you can use the `initialEditValue` to set the value of a new row: https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

Your columns definition would be:

```
columns: [
    {
        ...,
        title: 'date',
        field: 'fieldDate',
        type: 'date',
        initialEditValue: new Date()
    },
    ...
]
```